# vuejs serverPrefetch component data persists?

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

Stupid question but I haven't found a piece of doc that confirms it.

With vuejs ssr, if a value is set on a component `data` during `serverPrefetch`, is it meant to persist on client side?

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      count:0
    }
  },
  serverPrefetch(){
    this.count = 1
    return Promise.resolve(this.count)
  },
  mounted(){
    // can I rely on this?
    if(count===0){
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

My test shows that `count` is always zero on page refresh. If someone can please confirm this is standard behaviour and possibly explain why and/or direct me to a documentation about it.

Thank you

Comment: You don`t have access to "this" context on server side

Comment: You do have access to "this" in `serverPrefetch` https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/data.html#logic-collocation-with-components